# Number of ultrasound machines per country

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset listing how many ultrasound machines there are each country normalized by the population or number of physicians. Ideally, with some numbers showing the evolution over the year.

---

E.g., for MRI scanners, that would be:

[image]

[image]